# Проблема с Autowired - spring. Возвращает null

Tags: java, spring, vaadin

Со спрингом не дружу, только начинию изучать. Не могу понять, почему не хочет автоваридся PersistenceFacade. Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема. Уже много времени убил, чтобы разобраться. 
В спринг-контексте прописаны только бины для dataSourse - подключение к БД.

Вот тут фасад возвращает null.

```
@Component("gridClient")
public class ClientGrid extends CustomComponent {

@Autowired
PersistenceFacade facade;

VerticalLayout verticalLayout;

Grid<Client> grid;

public ClientGrid() {
    verticalLayout = new VerticalLayout();
    grid = new Grid<>();
    System.out.println("Facade: " + facade);
    setSettings();
    initGrid();
}
```

Тут, вроде как, инстанциирую ClientGrid.

```
heme("valo")
@SpringUI(path = "")
public class MainPage extends UI {

@Autowired
ClientGrid clientGrid;

@Override
protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
    VerticalLayout layoutMain = new VerticalLayout();
    setContent(layoutMain);

    WrapperMenu menu = new WrapperMenu();

    System.out.println("CLIENTGRID: " + clientGrid);

    layoutMain.addComponents(menu, clientGrid);
  }
}
```

Ну и сам PersistenceFacade. Вроде пометил его, как бин.

```
@Repository("persistenceFacade")
public class PersistenceFacade implements Facade {

    @Autowired
    private PersistenceManager manager;

    @Autowired
    private ConverterFactory converter;
```

Comment: А включен режим автопоиска бинов по аннотациям?

Comment: @VladimirParfenov да, включен.

Comment: PersistenceFacade подымается? туда инжектятся бины?

Answer (score 0):

Если установлена такая запись

```
@Autowired
PersistenceFacade facade;
```

то Spring будет искать бин с id "facade", так как не установлено другого. А сам бин объявлен так `@Repository("persistenceFacade")`, что означает, что у фасада id "persistenceFacade".

Варианты:

1. Изменить название поля с `facade` на `persistenceFacade`
2. Добавить полю аннотацию `@Qualifier("persistenceFacade")`

Comment: не помогает это тоже

Comment: Попробуйте в коде получить бин по id прямо из ссылки на контекст. Может он вообще не инициализируется.

Comment: А спринг разве по дефолту не ищет подходящие бины по типам? Если добавить аннотацию @Named("название бина") то да, он будет учитывать и имена

Comment: Зависит от способа инициализации спринга и типа контекста

Comment: Не слышал про такое, где про написано?

Comment: "Spring 4 для профессионалов"

Comment: я читал, не помню чтобы там было такое написано

Comment: Там не написано, а просто указан способ инициализации в коде Xml контекста, вместо Annotation контекста. Тогда нужно, если хочешь и то, и другое, выставить атрибут в xml об автоскане классов.

Comment: причем здесь типы контекстов спринга, мы говорим о способах поиска подходящего бина для инжекта, а это насколько мне известно в настройках не выставляется.

Comment: От типа контекста зависят дефолтные настройки поиска бина. Просто почитайте еще раз, если не верите. А наша дискуссия выходит за рамки вопроса.

Comment: @VladimirParfenov если вы про PersistenceFacade, то он инициализируется. Я его использовал уже, но в других классах.